# DatePicker bootstrap get date does not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to get the date from a datepicker input, but every time i tried i got this error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function                 bootstrap-datepicker.js:343
```

I can't figure what is wrong with my code:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    console.log($('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate'));
});
```

my jquery.js, bootstrap.js and datepicker.js are in order.

Comment: please provide the link for `datepicker.js` plugin

Comment: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/